# Can i add HIbernate functionality with spring security

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

Can i add hibernate functionality with spring security so that in respect of the code written below i can put some hibernate functionality so that it check database directly for username and password in respect of the code shown below.

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="ananth" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html). Read through various tutorials online for how to implement UserDetailsService.

After you have implemented UserDetailsService, use it as your authentication provider.
You authentication-manager will look something like this:

```
<authentication-manager>            
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">               
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

where 'userDetailsService' is bean that has implements UserDetailService.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authenticate your users via a database :

```
<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

       users-by-username-query="
          select username,password, enabled 
          from users where username=?" 

       authorities-by-username-query="
          select u.username, ur.authority from users u, authorities  ur 
          where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " 

    />
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Your database look like :

```
create table users(
  username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,
  password varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
  enabled boolean not null);

create table authorities (
  username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
  authority varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
  constraint fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references users(username));
  create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);
```

From [official Spring Security doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/appendix-schema.html)